# Tanstack query to fetch calendar data

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query, tanstackreact-query

In my react project I have a calendar component, which displays the events that the user has scheduled, the user can scroll through the months, every time the user switches to another month, the api sends a request /api/calendar?dateFrom=[first-day-of-month]&dateTo=[last-day-of-month]. The problem occurs when the user clicks in the application the detail of one of the events of the month (sidebar pops up) A and switches in the calendar to the month B, in the project we use react-query which at the moment when the user switches the month overwrites the original events with the events of the following month and the events of the previous month disappear.

So I would like to ask if you know any clever way to ensure that react query will add events from the next month to previous data instead of overwriting them

this is function used to fetch the calendar data

```
export const useGetCalendarEvents = (params: IGetCalendarEventsApiParams) => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  return {
    ...useQuery({
      queryKey: [QUERY_KEYS.CALENDAR_EVENTS, params],
      queryFn: () => getCalendarEvents(params),
    }),
    invalidate: () => queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: [QUERY_KEYS.CALENDAR_EVENTS] }),
  };
};
```

```
export interface IGetCalendarEventsApiParams {
  fromDate?: Date;
  toDate?: Date;
}
```

Ive tried using useInfiniteQuery but gave up, because iam not sure if it meets requirements I have

EDIT: this is how query keys look

[query keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5J6Rw.png)

Comment: It's pretty difficult for us to help without seeing your code that displays the event details. Can you provide that code?